# Using getActionCommand String to substring into a row and column

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a task where I create a GUI with Java. Currently, I am making a layout for Minesweeper - but I'm a bit puzzled with this method's instructions.

The instructions go as follows:

**mousePressed method**

- getActionCommand to get the String
- use getComponent and cast it to a button
- break the actionCommand String into a row and column
- set the button text of the row and column to "!"

This is what I have for `mousePressed()`

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent b)
    {
        
        Component a = b.getComponent(); 
        JButton x = (JButton)a;
        System.out.println(x.getActionCommand());
        String s = x.getActionCommand();
        // substring for row and col
        // set text
    }
```

How would I do the last two? Especially with

> break the actionCommand String into a row and column

> set the button text of the row and column to "!"

With substring, how would I go and "break" the actionCommand String into a row and column? (Break is not meant to be taken literally). Substring returns part of a string with a start index and end index, but what string from actionCommand would I use for the substring? And how would I set the row and column to show text as "!"? Would I need to use substring for this as well?

Here is my entire code for the layout so far.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridOfButtons extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
    private JButton [][] grid;

    public GridOfButtons()
    {
        grid = new JButton[10][10];
        BuildGUI();
    }
    
    public void BuildGUI()
    {
        setSize(1200, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        setVisible(true);

        for(int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++)
            {
                grid[r][c] = new JButton("*");
                grid[r][c].setActionCommand(r + ":" + c);
                addMouseListener(this);
                getContentPane().add(grid[r][c]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent b)
    {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent b)
    {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent b)
    {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent b)
    {
    }   

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent b)
    {
        
        Component a = b.getComponent(); 
        JButton x = (JButton)a;
        System.out.println(x.getActionCommand());
        String s = x.getActionCommand();
        // substring for row and col
        // set text
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GridOfButtons();
    }
}
```

These are also the instructions I followed:

Create a class that is a subclass of JFrame that uses interface MouseListener with:

**Instance variables:**

- a 2d array of JButtons

**Default constructor:**

- sets the size of the array to 10 by 10
- calls a method to build the GUI

**GUI builder method:**

- set default close
- sets the layout to GridLayout
- use nested for loops to create the button with initial text  "*"
- use setActionCommand to add the row + ":" + column
- add the Mouse listener
- add the button to the JFrame

**mousePressed method:**

- getActionCommand to get the String
- use getComponent and cast it to a button
- break the actionCommand String into a row and column
- set the button text of the row and column to "!"

I can't strictly adhere to the text (I'm adding other lines of code that aren't clarified in the instructions), but I can't do anything too advanced either since I'm working under constraints.

Comment: Why?  Why would you use a `MouseListener` this way?  `JButton` has a perfectly useable callback workflow, through it's `ActionListener` support.  The button should be linked to model in some way, then you won't need to care about decrypting the column/row information

Comment: *"How would I do the last two? "* - `String#split` and `JButton#setText`, but excuse me, the rest of the code/requirement just makes me want 

Comment: Sorry I'd do it a different way if I can but it's the only way I can do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am aware that with assignments you are often limited to use only the things that you have learned so far. Hence I understand that you can only use method `substring` (of class `java.lang.String`) to manipulate the text of each `JButton`. (I hope you can also use method `indexOf` because I use it in the below code.)

Apart from the [missing] code to change the `JButton` text, your code has two problems.

1. Calling method `setVisible` should be the last line of your `BuildGUI` method.
2. You are adding a `MouseListener` to the `JFrame`, i.e. to class `GridOfButtons`. You need to add a `MouseListener` to each `JButton`.

Here is your corrected code including the code to change the `JButton` text. As stated above, I moved the line `setVisible(true);`. I also added a `MouseListener` to each `JButton`. (See the comment *CHANGE HERE* in the below code.) And I added code to change the `JButton` text in method `mousePressed`.

```java
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GridOfButtons extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    private JButton [][] grid;

    public GridOfButtons()
    {
        grid = new JButton[10][10];
        BuildGUI();
    }
    
    public void BuildGUI()
    {
        setSize(1200, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));

        for(int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++)
            {
                grid[r][c] = new JButton("*");
                grid[r][c].setActionCommand(r + ":" + c);
                grid[r][c].addMouseListener(this); // CHANGE HERE
                getContentPane().add(grid[r][c]);
            }
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent b)
    {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent b)
    {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent b)
    {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent b)
    {
    }   

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent b)
    {
        Component a = b.getComponent(); 
        JButton x = (JButton)a;
        System.out.println(x.getActionCommand());
        String s = x.getActionCommand();
        // substring for row and col
        // set text
        int ndx = s.indexOf(':');
        if (ndx >= 0) {
            String row = s.substring(0, ndx);
            String col = s.substring(ndx + 1);
            String text = row + '!' + col;
            x.setText(text);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GridOfButtons();
    }
}
```

Some notes regarding the above code.

1. It is recommended to use [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) which means that method `BuildGui` should be named `buildGui`.
2. It is usually better to set one of the dimensions to 0 (zero) in the `GridLayout` constructor. Refer to [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).
3. Most of the "listener" interfaces have a corresponding "adapter" class that implements the interface. For `MouseListener` there is class `MouseAdapter`. This saves you from having to write implementations for every method in the listener interface. Refer to [How to Write a Mouse Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).
4. Usually you would add an `ActionListener` to a `JButton`, rather than a `MouseListener`. Refer to [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). But I assume that your professor has a reason for setting the assignment requirements.

Here is a screen capture of the running app after clicking on the `JButton` in the first column of the first row in the grid.

[image: screen capture of running app]